# I am getting this error with R version 3.3.2 in Mac OS #Error: protect(): protection stack overflow

Tags: r

I am getting this error with R version 3.3.2 in Mac OS:

```
#Error: protect(): protection stack overflow
```

I opened `RStudio` with command line option `--max-ppsize 500000`, but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: we need a lot more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: More information:  Actually I am building a model with n-gram. I have a huge matrix something around ( 3000 by 27000). I am getting this error when I run the heavy computation part.  I just have 8GB ram in my computer, so I tried to fire an ec2 instance with 16gb ram and run the model, but unfortunately got the same error. I am stucked  at this point and don't know why else to try.

Comment: we can't help without at least an attempt on your part at a reproducible example ...

Comment: @BenBolker TextAnalytics.R is the script I am running, [link] (https://github.com/usapkota/TextMining/blob/master/TextAnalytics.R)  The code at line 237 is what is giving me the error.

Comment: I don't know.  Can you make `max-ppsize` even larger (say 1000000) ?

Comment: @BenBolker the maximum value accepted is 500000.

Comment: @BenBolker I think i need to use a more powerful cluster, I will try that. Thank you for your help.