# How to set R max ppsize for RStudio on macOS

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm getting an error in RStudio that has already been described in other posts:

```
> Error: protect(): protection stack overflow
```

I want to try and change the `max ppsize` when starting RStudio from the command line, but I can't find any description on how to do this on macOS.

Using Terminal, I called `open -a rstudio --max-ppsize=500000`, which gave me:

```
open: unrecognized option `--max-ppsize=500000'
```

Thanks for any help.

---

related posts:

[How to set max ppsize in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728774/how-to-set-max-ppsize-in-r)

[I am getting this error with R version 3.3.2 in Mac OS #Error: protect(): protection stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715830/i-am-getting-this-error-with-r-version-3-3-2-in-mac-os-error-protect-protec)

Comment: You can run your R script with that option from the command line (e.g. `Rscript --vanilla --max-ppsize=500000 ml_pipeline_v6.12.R`) but I don't believe that's a setting you can specify in Rstudio. There are workarounds to pass arguments to Rscript via Rstudio (e.g. using `system()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980322/is-it-possible-to-specify-command-line-parameters-to-r-script-in-rstudio) but I don't know if it will work to solve your problem. What are you running that is causing that error?

Comment: I don't have an R script, but an Rproject that I work on using RStudio. I'm using environments as hash tables that have up to 100.000 entries. It might just be a bug (see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414426/using-large-hash-tables-in-r) ), but I wanted to try out the `max ppsize` anyway.